# Hashicorp Vault - Send command or api call on variable edit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault, gitlab-api

Let's suppose I make a change over one variable in a Key-Value engine in my Hashicorp Vault.

Once I apply the change, it will create a new version of my variable, as expected.

Can I, somehow, send an API call or at least run a command coming from Hashicorp Vault itself? What I want to achieve is that, when I change a variable inside Hashicorp Vault, I can trigger a CICD build inside Gitlab CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Hashicorp Vault itself does not have any event/callback or similar mechanism for when secrets are updated.

However, depending on what [storage backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage) you are using, you may be able to use features of your backend to support this. To give a few examples:

- If you are using Consul as the backend for Vault, you can use [watches](https://www.consul.io/docs/dynamic-app-config/watches) in Consul to monitor for key/value pair changes.
- If you are using DynamoDB, you can configure [streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) to trigger other workflows, like a lambda function to run your pipeline.
- If you are using S3 as the storage backend, you can leverage [S3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html)

Other backends will have their own mechanisms for this. However, not all backends will support this directly.

If you don't have a backend that supports this, your next best bet would be to periodically poll and check for updated values. For example, you might use [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) to do this.